# Javascript parse excel file and create cartesian product

Tags: javascript, node.js, cartesian-product

I have an excel file that contains two sheets. One is the `source` sheet which contains a list of ID's. The second sheet is the data which has three columns.

I am trying to parse this document and create a cartesian product from the two sheets.
For every ID on the `source` sheet, it needs to have be combined with every row on the `data` sheet.

**Example:**

Sheet 1 (Source):

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Sheet 2 (Data):

```
Bob, 20, Arizona
James, 30, California
Sam, 40, Florida
```

Expected Output:

```
Bob, 20, Arizona, ABC
James, 30, California, ABC
Sam, 40, Florida, ABC

Bob, 20, Arizona, DEF
James, 30, California, DEF
Sam, 40, Florida, DEF

Bob, 20, Arizona, GHI
James, 30, California, GHI
Sam, 40, Florida, GHI
```

I am using `nodejs` to parse this xlsx file and iterate over the sheets. I am getting two arrays, each with the correct data that looks like this.

```
[
  { SourceId: 'ABC' },
  { SourceId: 'DEF' },
  { SourceId: 'GHI' }
]
[
  { Name: 'Bob', Age: 20, Location: 'Arizona' },
  { Name: 'James', Age: 30, Location: 'California' },
  { Name: 'Sam', Age: 40, Location: 'Florida' }
]
```

I am now trying to combined the two where each row in data maps to each row in the source. In my example, there are 3 rows of data and 3 source Ids. This could create an output of 9 results.

If these were both arrays, it would be straight forward, but I am having trouble figuring out how to add them to the data object.

**Code:**

```
var XLSX = require("xlsx");
var workbook = XLSX.readFile("data.xlsx");
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) {
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];
  var worksheetName = y;
  var headers = {};
  var data = [];
  var primarySet = [];

  for (z in worksheet) {
    if (z[0] === "!") continue;

    //parse out the column, row, and value
    var col = z.substring(0, 1);
    var row = parseInt(z.substring(1));
    var value = worksheet[z].v;

    //store header names
    if (row == 1) {
      headers[col] = value;
      continue;
    }

    if (worksheetName == "Source") {
      if (!primarySet[[row]]) {
        primarySet[row] = {};
      }
      primarySet[row][headers[col]] = value;
    }

    if (!data[row]) {
      data[row] = {};
    }
    data[row][headers[col]] = value;

  }
  //drop those first two rows which are empty
  data.shift();
  data.shift();
  console.log(data);

  /* Expected Output

  [
    { Name: 'Bob', Age: 20, Location: 'Arizona', SourceId: 'ABC' },
    { Name: 'James', Age: 30, Location: 'California', SourceId: 'ABC' },
    { Name: 'Sam', Age: 40, Location: 'Florida', SourceId: 'ABC' },

    { Name: 'Bob', Age: 20, Location: 'Arizona', SourceId: 'DEF' },
    { Name: 'James', Age: 30, Location: 'California', SourceId: 'DEF' },
    { Name: 'Sam', Age: 40, Location: 'Florida', SourceId: 'DEF' },

    { Name: 'Bob', Age: 20, Location: 'Arizona', SourceId: 'GHI' },
    { Name: 'James', Age: 30, Location: 'California', SourceId: 'GHI' },
    { Name: 'Sam', Age: 40, Location: 'Florida', SourceId: 'GHI' },

]

   */

});
```

Is there a good way to handle this where I can essentially merge the source into the data `n` times?

Comment: have you tried `flatMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `flatMap` to get the expected output:

```js
var arr1 = [ { SourceId: 'ABC' }, { SourceId: 'DEF' }, { SourceId: 'GHI' }];
var arr2 = [ { Name: 'Bob', Age: 20, Location: 'Arizona' }, { Name: 'James', Age: 30, Location: 'California' }, { Name: 'Sam', Age: 40, Location: 'Florida' }];

var result = arr1.flatMap(({SourceId},i)=>arr2.map(val=>({...val, SourceId})));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is working. Just curious, can `SourceId` be dynamic in the result? I.e Can it use the property key from `arr1` so that if the column name in array1 ended up being `SrcId`, the `flatMap` and `map` would still work as it would dynamically use the key name vs hardcoding it?

Comment: @SBB I have destructured the object here(`SourceId`), so every time if this misses key of that name in array, it would be `undefined`. It will work properly if it is consistent.

Comment: Totally understand, was just trying to think of a way to make it dynamic so the column name could be user defined and the code wasn't looking for something specific. Unrelated to this question though, I will look into that. Thanks!